# FTP downloading blank PDF vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ftp, download

So I have written code which manages to upload a pdf file onto a FTP server. once on the server, I can download it from the server via Chrome and it will work fine. but I want to download it via my program, so i wrote some more code which sort of does this however, the size of the file i get is 0kb, so is empty. How do i fix this?

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim output As IO.Stream
    Dim FileName As String
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the file to download:")
    FileName = Console.ReadLine
    Try
        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest
        request = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/Folder/" & FileName & ".pdf"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        'request.Method=Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize 
        'FileLength = cint(FTPRequest.getresponse.contentLength)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Try
        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest
        request = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.server.com/Folder/" & FileName & ".pdf"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password")
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
        'Dim OutPutFilepath As String = "DownloadTest" & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName("ftp://ftp.Server.com/Folder/")
        output = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\TestFile2.pdf")

        output.Close()
        stream.Close()
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded")
        Console.ReadLine()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to be writing `stream` to the file that you create (`output`). You just close both the stream and file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you write the data from your stream to your file:

```
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
    output = System.IO.File.Create("C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\TestFile2.pdf")
    stream.CopyTo(output)
    output.Close()
    stream.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.